# Find lastly added collection with some condition in MongoDB and C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I am working a asp .net 6.0 with mongoDB.

I have a query to filter hotel results.

```
public async Task<List<HotelResultDocument>> GetHotelResults(List<string> rateKeys)
    {
        var filter = Builders<HotelResultDocument>.Filter.In(x => x.RateKey, rateKeys);

        filter &= Builders<HotelResultDocument>.Filter.Eq(x => x.RateType, "BOOKABLE");

        filter &= Builders<HotelResultDocument>.Filter.Gt(x => x.ExpiredAt, DateTime.Now);

        return await _hotelResultsCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Here My issue is There are more than one responses for same rateKEy with "BOOKABLE" type. I want only lastly added collection with a rateKEy with "BOOKABLE" type.

How to filter to get above response?

```
public class HotelResultDocument
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Reference { get; set; }

        public string Token { get; set; }

        public int HotelCode { get; set; }

        public string RateKey { get; set; }

        public string RateClass { get; set; }

        public string RateType { get; set; }

        public double Net { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTime ExpiredAt { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note :
If I sent four rateKeys I have to find the hotels for each rateKeys (if the hotel satisfied above conditions.)
But using above query I got more then one hotel for a rateKey. I have to find the lastly added hotel for a particular rateKey.**

Edit :
Current Response

```
"hotel" : [
{
   "hotelCode" : 2,
   "CreatedAt" :{26/07/2022 03:50:26},
   "RateKey" : 1,
},

{
   "hotelCode" : 2,
   "CreatedAt" :{26/07/2022 03:51:26},
   "RateKey" : 1,
},

{
   "hotelCode" : 2,
   "CreatedAt" :{26/07/2022 03:52:26},
   "RateKey" : 1,
},

{
   "hotelCode" : 2,
   "CreatedAt" :{26/07/2022 03:54:26},
   "RateKey" : 1,
},

{
   "hotelCode" : 4,
   "CreatedAt" :{26/07/2022 03:52:26},
   "RateKey" : 5,
},

{
   "hotelCode" : 4,
   "CreatedAt" :{26/07/2022 03:55:26},
   "RateKey" : 5,
}
]
```

Expected Response :

```
"hotel" : [

{
   "hotelCode" : 2,
   "CreatedAt" :{26/07/2022 03:54:26}, 
   "RateKey" : 1,
},

{
   "hotelCode" : 4,
   "CreatedAt" :{26/07/2022 03:55:26},
   "RateKey" : 5,
}
]
```

Anyone help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your documents?

Comment: Did your document contains field such as `CreatedDate`, for keeping track the date that the document is created?

Comment: @YongShun yes, I have updated the question with model. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can achieve it with Aggregation Pipeline.

**Updated based on Post Owner's requirements**

1. `$match` - Filter documents.
2. `$sort` - Order by `CreatedAt` descending.
3. `$group` - Group by `RateKey` and take the first document as `hotel`.
4. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with `hotel`.

> MongoDB query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      CreatedAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$RateKey",
      hotel: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$hotel"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N1eMYIB9Gs6)

---

> MongoDB .NET driver C# syntax

```cs
public class GroupedHotelResult
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("hotel")]
    public HotelResultDocument Hotel { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
SortDefinition<HotelResultDocument> sort =
    Builders<HotelResultDocument>.Sort.Descending(x => x.CreatedAt);

ProjectionDefinition<HotelResultDocument, GroupedHotelResult> group =
    new BsonDocument
    {
        { "_id", "$RateKey" },
        { "hotel", new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$first", "$$ROOT" }
            }
        }
    };

return await _collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(filter)
    .Sort(sort)
    .Group<GroupedHotelResult>(group)
    .ReplaceWith<GroupedHotelResult, HotelResultDocument>(x => x.Hotel)
    .ToListAsync();
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: No this give only one hotel result in the list. My requirement is different from this. For each rate key, I have to find a hotel.
Using above query, I got only one hotel in request for 2 ratekeys.

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the sample input and expected output documents to the question.

Comment: Your query limit the final hotels list. But it should sort when selecting hotel for a rate key according to the  createdAt, then it should list the  hotels for all rateKey.
(a ratekey can have a hotel not more than one)

Comment: While let's say you pass "Key 1", "Key 2", "Key 3" and "Key 4", you want to get the lastly added documents which contain one of these (parsed) key? Sound like group by each key?

Comment: I have updated the questions, Please check

Comment: Yes similar to group by each key.

Comment: Done update the answer, should be meet your requirements.

Comment: I did like this This is also worked,"
`
var filter = Builders<HotelResultDocument>.Filter.In(x => x.RateKey, rateKeys);

        filter &= Builders<HotelResultDocument>.Filter.Eq(x => x.RateType, "BOOKABLE");

        filter &= Builders<HotelResultDocument>.Filter.Gt(x => x.ExpiredAt, DateTime.Now);

        var hotels = await _hotelResultsCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

        var groupedHotel = hotels.GroupBy(x => x.RateKey)
         .SelectMany(t => t.OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedAt).Take(1)).ToList();

        return groupedHotel;
`